# Edge-disjoint path-systems in infinite digraphs

Tags: co.combinatorics, graph-theory, infinite-combinatorics

Let $ D=(V,A) $ be a directed graph without backward-infinite paths and let $ \{ s_i \}_{i<\lambda},U \subset V $ where $ 
\lambda $ is some cardinal. Assume that for all $ u\in U $ there is a system of edge-disjoint paths $ \{ P_i \}_{i<\lambda} $ 
such that $ P_i $ goes from $ s_i $ to $ u $ and for all $ v\in V\setminus U $ there is a system of edge-disjoint paths $ \{ Q_i 
\}_{i<\lambda} $ such that $ Q_i $ goes either from $ s_i $ to $ v $ or from $ U $ to $ v $. Is it true that then for all $ v\in 
V $ there is a system of edge-disjoint paths $ \{ P_i \}_{i<\lambda} $ such that $ P_i  $ goes from $ s_i $ to $ v $?